# ASP.NET MVC 2 IgnoreRoute in all directories

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I switched from MVC 1 to MVC 2. I am using a file.axd httphandler in my application and I set `routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");` in my global routing. Since MVC 2 MVC only ignores requests to `/file.axd` but **not** to `/folder/file.axd.`

Any changes in MVC 2?

I just want to make sure that all requests in any folder to any .axd file will get processed by my httphandler.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

```
routes.IgnoreRoute("{*allaxd}", new { allaxd = @".*\.axd(/.*)?" });
```

Thanks to HAACKED: http://haacked.com/archive/2008/07/14/make-routing-ignore-requests-for-a-file-extension.aspx